# How can we call a instance method with its class name? in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in rails guides
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html    instance method welcome_email(user) is defined in UserMailer class and now in UsersController create method how he is calling a instance method with class name i.e UserMailer.

Comment: This was ruthlessly downvoted. It's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

This is no doubt due to the much-lauded, yet much-reviled "magic" of Rails. I'd encourage you to read the [code for ActionMailer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb) and try to work it out for yourself. You'll probably find it is much more complicated than you first thought!

If you are familiar with Byebug, try inserting a 'byebug' statement inside the `welcome_email` method and calling it via `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user)`. Use 'up' and 'down' within the Byebug prompt to navigate the stack frames and see how the mailer instance is created and how instance method is actually invoked.